# What's the proper the structure for storing a big array which will be frequently updated

Tags: c++, objective-c, data-structures

I'm seeking for a proper structure for a big array which will be frequently updated. Thanks for your help!
Here's the background:
I want to draw a continuous curve to represent a sound wave in a certain time period. For the accuracy, the array length will be nearly 44100(the CD format)．And I just want to represent the last second wave, so the array will be updated very frequently - for every 1/44100 sec, the first element will be eliminated and a new last element will be inserted to the array.

For avoiding the frequent "malloc/realloc/new", what my current solution is using an Circular Queue which has a fixed size as 44100, but somehow I don't feel this is most proper solution, if I want to dynamically resize the queue, it will be a heavy cost.
This kind of situation should be quite often, I think there maybe some good patent for this issue. 
Thanks guys!

Comment: How frequently do you need to resize it?  Do you need to maintain the existing data when you resize it?

Comment: Take a look at `std::deque` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque).

Comment: Regarding performance, I don't see how you're going to get more efficient than using a fixed length single allocation and index-math to know where the prior and current waves stop and start within it. given the constraints of your usage, under what conditions and frequency would you need to resize this thing? If it is remotely frequently I concur with Captain Obvlious. Keep the circular indexing your using, but lay it on top of a std::deque for resizing.

Comment: Where are you resizing?Can you please clarify this?When you are updating after 1/44100 of a second, only one element is removed and one element is added, right?Or is one element removed, and many elements need to be added?Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need something specific, circular buffer seems OK. in some rare cases, double linked list (std::list) may be useful, as it supports fast insertions/resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're always having a fixed number of items in the array. As such I'd just use a ring buffer in any case (not sure whether that's what you refer to as a "Circular Queue", but I assume you'd use a dynamic length? If so, why? Is there no specific absolute (and practical) maximum?), i.e. a static array with a variable entry point as its start:

```
const unsigned int buffer_length = 500000;
float *buffer = new float[buffer_length];

unsigned int buffer_write = 0;

// append a value...
buffer[buffer_write] = my_value;
// ...and move the write/end position:
buffer_write = (buffer_write + 1) % buffer_length;
```

To output/use the values, you can use the following formula for index of the first entry to read:

```
unsigned int start_position = (buffer_length + buffer_write - length_to_read) % buffer_length;
```

To iterate, you just add position after position, again using modulo to jump back to the beginning of the array.

Comment: Thanks very much! And you are right, by the "circular Queue", I means the quite same thing as your "ring buffer". For the dynamic length requirement, because I want to allow user to adjust the time interval, i.e. from 1 sec time interval to 2 sec. Right now I just use the max length for the buffer which allow 10 sec, but somehow I feel it not quite flexible and too much memory consumption.

Comment: You could just resize the array just in time (i.e. if the number of requested elements doesn't fit in there anymore). You'd just make sure to retain the order of your existing elements.